# Аватары в социальной сети

Tags: php, mysql

Как организовать авы в соц.сети? То есть как сделать так, чтобы у каждого пользователя была своя ава?

Comment: вы конкретно про какую то соц сеть спрашиваете, или вам нужен общий принцип реализации?

Comment: Лучше конечно общий принцип реализации, но можно и Вконтакте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таблица в БД с ID загружаемых фотк ну а в профиль выводить.

Пользователь загружает фотку, нужного нам размера, или мы сами выставляем размер.

Ну и всё, принцип примерно такой.

ну в профиле создаешь форму для загрузки аватарок.

пользователь грузит картинку, при удачной загрузке в бд заносишь, допустим, название файла, а лучше переделать файл в вид удобный для тебя

```
$ext=explode(".",$_POST['file']);
$filename = $_POST['usr_name']."_".date().".".$ext[1];
```

получишь что-то вроде

```
shrek_1322642181.jpg
```

В БД занесешь инфу по новому названию файла. 
Ну а в профиль выводишь фотку

структура таблицы прмерно такая

```
ID - id записи
UID -id пользователя
AVATAR-название файла
```

ну к тому же грузить фотки лучше в отдельную папку на серваке, допустим, в

```
/Avatar/shrek/shrek_1322642181.jpg
или
/Avatar/UID/shrek_1322642181.jpg
```

Ну так вот. если по быстрому объяснить.

Comment: А куда и как загружать фотки?

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: О_о что значит куда и как? куда? на сайт. Как? Пишешь аплоад для картинок,загружаешь, заносишь в базу, где нужно выводишь...